# Who is a bad wife? (that you are obligated to divorce?)

Tags: halacha, marriage, mitzvah, divorce

Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer [119.4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x8102) said that there's is a Mitzva to divorce one's bad wife.

> אִשָּׁה רָעָה (ה) בְּדֵעוֹתֶיהָ, וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ צְנוּעָה כִּבְנוֹת יִשְׂרָאֵל הַכְּשֵׁרוֹת, מִצְוָה לְגָרְשָׁהּ:‏ 
>
> A wife who has a bad temper (Baer Heytev (paraphrasing Yevamot 63b: One who prepares for him the tray and turns her back upon him.) and which is not modest as Yisrael girls, and who is quarrelsome, it is a mitsva to divorce even if she is the first wife

What is considered a bad wife?
Bais Shmuel [there](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.119.4?with=Beit%20Shmuel) said:

> **היינו מקשטא ליה תכא ומהדרא ליה גבה שהיא בעלת מריבה מצוה לגרשה...‏**
>   **Which I do not know what does it mean?**

---

> What I found is [Yevamos 63b](http://halakhah.com/yebamoth/yebamoth_63.html): 
>   
> "One who prepares for him (Her husband) the tray and turns her back upon him (Euphemism)."

But I do not understand it.
How is the "Euphemism" understood?

Comment: See Mishna on chapter 5 ktubot

Comment: @kouty ? Which one? (I do not see one on topic)

Comment: 7,6 sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Yebamot 63b](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Yevamoth&df=63b), see Mishna Ketubot 7, 6

 תכא is table, it is a modest (tsniut) figurative image related to conjugal life.
See Nedarim [20b](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Nedarim&df=20b) for the use of the word "table" (A woman once came before Rabbi and said, 'Rabbi! I set a table before my husband,)
See Rabi [Yehuda Bar Natan](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47913&st=&pgnum=1116&hilite=)

1. ‎
   מקשטא ליה פומא‏ ‎=‏ wait until a meal to offend
   ‎
2. מהדרא ליה גבא= turn her back to not eat together (**Kepshuto, not euphemism**)
3. בעלת מריבה= is arguing always, loves to arguing

Comment: Why dont you cite the gemorah?

Comment: @hazoriz   I explained euphemism

Comment: @hazoriz I also give an example from gemara nedarim

Comment: +1 thank you, but did not yet explain what means 'bad', what means ומהדרא ליה גבה, what means שהיא בעלת מריבה,

Comment: (What means  ומקשטא ליה פומא)?

Comment: @hazoriz I tried to fix it