# Sources that it is also the husbands responsibility to make peace between a husband and wife (or examples where he does it)

Tags: words, marriage, shalom-peace

Sources that it is also the husbands responsibility to make peace between a husband and wife (or sources of examples of where a man does it)

(are we not thought the opposite, not that he should try to make peace but that he should [divorce a bad (meaning one that causes fights) wife](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71054)?)

**It seems that the Talmud only brings examples of the wife trying to make peace with her husband and never the other way.**
(examples, to drink the sota water to permit her, to [spit at a rabbi to permit her](http://chabad.org/2868331), Rabbi looks for where she has no blemish [nedorim 66b](http://halakhah.com/nedarim/nedarim_66.html),).

Is this incorrect?
What are the first sources that it is also the **husbands** responsibility (as we are thought now in modern society) to do more then his usual obligations to make peace?

Comment: I guess the reason why the examples are of the wife is because she was the one who wanted to stay married and the husband can always give a get when he wants, but now that a husband can't give a divorce it changed

Comment: Personally I think that it is fairly obvious that in any relationship involving multiple parties, all parties need to do all possible to add peace...

Comment: @mevaqesh (regarding your first comment) since I did not receive one , I removed the tag, I want any sources but the earlier the better, regarding your second comment please bring a source for tbat (that will be an answer)

Comment: למה לי קרא סברא הוא

Comment: @mevaqesh what happens with the svara if it seems to contradict a source see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71054

Comment: Consider asking that as a separate general question. | The particular sources you link to seem wholly irrelevant to the question at hand. First of all, in the linked question you admit to not knowing the translation of the sources; this hardly makes for a strong basis for a question. More significantly, however, is that none of those sources state that that in marriage in particular, or any relationship in general, that all parties need not do all possible to promote peace. | Furthermore, I don't know why you think this wouldn't be included the mitsvah d'orayta of ואהבת לרעך כמוך.

Comment: `are we not thought the opposite, not that he should try to make peace but that he should divorce a bad (meaning one that causes fights) wife?)` Why are those dichotomous? It can be the responsibility of a husband to promote peace to the extent of his capacity... _while he is married_, but that in no way precludes the possibility that divorce may sometimes be appropriate. | Consider clarifying what exactly you are asking.

Comment: `What are the first sources that it is also the husbands responsibility (as we are thought now in modern society)`  Consider clarifying what you believe is taught in modern society so readers have a better idea of what you are looking for. `to do more then his usual obligations to make peace?` So you are looking for obligations to do things that arent obligatory. Or responsibilities to do something? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Note that based on [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73389/sources-that-it-is-also-the-husbands-responsibility-to-make-peace-between-a-husb#comment241398_73444) it appears that your latest edit invalidates (at least in your opinion) the existing upvoted answer. Such edits are not allowed. Once an answer is upvoted it cannot be invalidated through an edit. Rather you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The Babylonian Talmud has several references in this regard. First, in [b. *Baba Mezi'a* (Folio 59a)](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Baba-Metzia&df=59a) we read the following with regard to instigating conflict with ones wife -

> R. Hanina, son of R. Idi, said: What is meant by the verse, Ye shall not wrong one another [עֲמִית֔וֹ] (Lev 25:17)? — Wrong not a people that is with you in learning and good deeds.
>
> Rab said: ***One should always be heedful of wronging his wife***, for since her tears are frequent; she is quickly hurt.
>
> (*emphasis added*)

Second, the husband is to cherish his wife in order to maintain domestic tranquility according to [b. *Yevamoth* (Folio 62b)](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Yevamoth&df=62b). The `notes in gray boxes` come from [dTorah.com](http://dtorah.com/), and [notes in brackets] are my own -

> R'Tanhum stated in the name of R'Hanilai: Any man who has no wife lives without joy, without blessing, and without goodness, without joy' - for it is written.
>
> And thou shalt rejoice, thou and thy house `(= wife [Yoma 2a])`. 'Without blessing', for it is written, To cause a blessing to rest on thy house `(Ezek 44:30)`. 'Without goodness', for it is written, I is not good that the man should be alone `(Gen 2:18)`.
>
> In the West `(Palestine)` it was stated `(concerning the unmarried man)`: Without Torah and without a [protecting] wall.'
>
> 'Without Torah' - for it is written.
>
> Is it that I have no help `(= wife)` in me, and that sound wisdom `(= Torah)` is driven quite from me `(Job 6:13)`? 'Without a [protecting] wall', for it is written, 'A woman shall encompass a man'`(Jer 31:22)`.
>
> Raba B'Ulla said `(concerning the unmarried man)`: Without peace, for it is written, And thou shalt know that thy tent `(= wife)` is in peace; and thou shalt visit ["ופקדת" = conjugal relations] thy habitation [= wife] and shalt miss nothing `(Job 5:24)`.
>
> R'Joshua B'Levi said: Whosoever knows his wife to be a God-fearing woman and does not duly visit her ["לפקוד" = conjugal relations] is called a sinner; for it is said, And thou shalt know that thy tent is in peace, etc.
>
> R'Joshua B'Levi further stated: It is a man's duty to pay a visit to his wife when he starts on a journey; it is said, And thou shalt know that thy tent `(= wife)` is in peace, etc.

The final sentence (above) repeated the previous sentence, but left out the reference that the wife be someone "God-fearing" in order to receive cherished treatment from her husband.

Finally, it is ironic that many references in this passage from Talmud come from the Book of Job, whose wife had once advised him "to curse God and die" (Job 2:9), and yet the commands here in Talmud are upon the husband to cherish his wife notwithstanding.

In summary, these passages seem to indicate that the husband take the initiative for maintaining domestic tranquility notwithstanding that the wife may not be "God-fearing."

Comment: +1 but are all those things not his usual obligations?